# Opening a new page in php on a button press

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want a new page to be opened when a button is pressed. Here is my code so far:

```
<input name="newThread" type="button" value="New Discussion" onclick="window.open('Political/Thread/thread_insert.php')"/>
```

It fails, however, ..I think the path is incorrect, but I dont know why..cause it is the correct directory path...

Comment: the opening of the new page works for me. If you're not landing on the right page, your path *must* be wrong. Maybe try an absolute path

Comment: How do I acheive so? ..that is the absolute path.. :(

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct (valid and function), you problem is the your path.

Remember that page location is the page inside the web server and relative to the current page location.

So if your web server root is for example `c:\wamp\www` then the web address `test/test.php` will look for the real page of `c:\wamp\www\test\test.php`. However the same address encoded into a page already in a subdirectory will be relative unless it starts with `/`
So from the page test/test.php in the above example the link to `test/test.php` will become `/test/test/test.php` (with a real path of `c:\wamp\www\test\test\test.php`)

If you have copied the link from another page somewhere this is probably the problem

Comment: This shouldn't be relevant. The internal server settings have no impact on the users perception of the URL.

Comment: I only include they statement because the original poster said the path was the correct directory path and as it seems that the problem is something to do with paths the original poster may be confusing a directory path with a web address path.

Comment: Having read through it again, you're just stating things in a weird way. Real path locations are an implementation detail. We only care about web addresses. The point itself is correct though.

Comment: I think that you identified the problem. I need to be careful with my redirects and includes, when designing where each file will lie

Answer (score 9):

This will open a new tab/window (depending on the user's settings):

```
<a class="button" href="Political/Thread/thread_insert.php" target="_blank">New Discussion</a>
```

To make this "a button":

```css
a.button {
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    background: #a0a0a0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I stated, that I want it to be a button

Comment: I thought about doing so too. But I would rather it to look like a button..  I found something that works:  <input name="newThread" type="button" value="New Discussion" onclick="location.href='../Thread/thread_insert.php?topic=World_Leaders'"/>

Comment: @Matrix: Tough. It's not a button. It's a link, because it opens a new page. Links should be marked up with the `<a>` tag. What exactly do you mean by "look like a button"?

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code,

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Click" onClick="window.open('Political/Thread/thread_insert.php','windowname',' width=400,height=200')">
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, i used a href="linkName.php".. it worked. the path was incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="Political/Thread/thread_insert.php" target="_blank" action="post">
<input name="newThread" type="submit" value="New Discussion" />
</form>
```

Tested and working. You can leave the action empty if you want.

Or

```
<form action="Political/Thread/thread_insert.php" target="_blank" action="">
<button>New Discussion</button>
</form>
```

But as said in one of the other answers, you better go with a link and style it like a button. Using javascript or making forms to achieve the same results is just more work and well... bad.

Comment: Either way, if you're doing anything other then using a link for this. You're doing it wrong. I just provided an answer that works because you want to have a button, not one you should be using.

Comment: @Matrix001: Rather a form than javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 <a href="../Myfolder/yourfile.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default subs-btn">Join</a>
```

class="btn 
btn is the style class of the button.

And f you want a direct link to the file and not have to go into an external folder:

```
<a href="yourfile.html" type="button" class="btn btn-default subs-btn">Join</a>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Add below properties to element and it will look exactly same as button

Disable text-decoration for link for better effect

```
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: outset;
border-image: initial;
-webkit-appearance: push-button;
-webkit-user-select: none;
white-space: pre;
text-rendering: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
font: 13.3333px Arial;
```

I know it's too late but I'm putting it for other people who is looking for the same answer

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['myButtonName'])){
  header("Location:newPage.php");
  exit();
}

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   <button style="margin-left:5px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="myButtonName">Open</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks